# AJAX, запрос без url

Tags: jquery, url, ajax, javascript, post

пытаюсь отправить запрос POST , на сколько я знаю если через POST , то данные не должны быть видны в запросе url

вот пытаюсь отправить такой запрос , но все равно формируется url как при get запросе, как обойти это? хотелось бы именно без перезагрузке странице

вот код

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#install_form").submit(function(){
        var name_db = $("#name_db").val();        
        var name_user_db = $("#name_user_db").val();
        var pass_user_db = $("#pass_user_db").val();
        var email_admin = $("#email_admin").val();
        var login_admin = $("#login_admin").val();
        var pass_admin = $("#pass_admin").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../db_connect/index.php",
            data: { name_db: name_db , name_user_db: name_user_db, name : value }
            success: function()
            {
                alert("111");
            }
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: собирать данные с формы удобнее через $("form#install_formm").serialize(); это будет encode (%20)
или так в чистом виде
$("form#install_form").submit(function(event) {
  console.log( $("form#install_form").serializeArray());
  event.preventDefault();
});

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете аякс, да еще и нужно без перезагрузки - то зачем вам форма?.. 
Выкиньте ее, `<input type="submit">` замените на `<button>` у которого на onclick повесьте обработчик вашего аякс-запроса..

Comment: у меня и так button, но как это поможет? проблема остается
мне надо что бы параметров не было в url при передаче

Comment: @scp7 вам выше русским языком сказали - если вы используете ajax, то зачем вам форма? Более того, если вы и параметры запроса получаете через jQuery, а не через привязку формы, то ее наличие становится вдвойне бессмысленным. А вот использование исключительно ajax позволит вам не делать перезагрузку страницы, и, соответственно, не менять текущий url страницы

Comment: @DreamChild делаю так , но не работает, подскажите что не так
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="aaa" onclick="asd()">Установить</button>

 $(document).ready(function(){

             function asd(){
                 var name_db = $("#name_db").val();
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "../db_connect/index.php",
                     data: { name_db: name_db}
                 });
                  return 0;
              }
             });

Comment: > делаю так , но не работает

что конкретно не работает? Сделайте jsfiddle, заниматься телепатией не хотелось бы

Comment: вынесите asd() из области $(document).ready(function(){}, и куда делась ветка success: function(){} в аякс?..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#install_form").submit(function(event) {}); // нужно ловить этот эвент, а потом юзать.
```

Comment: пишу так, результат не меняется все равно

$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#install_form").submit(function(event) {

            var name_db = $("#name_db").val();
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "../db_connect/index.php",
                     data: { name_db: name_db }
                     success: function()
                     {
                         alert("111");
                     }
                 })
                  event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

Comment: @scp7, после этого data: { name_db: name_db , name_user_db: name_user_db, name : value } нужно поставить запятую

Comment: @scp7 ... и в консоль заглядывать.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать не

```
$.ajax()
```

а непосредственно post

```
$.post('../db_connect/index.php', {name_db: name_db}, function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить `method: 'POST'` вот так

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "...",
    data: {...}
    method: 'POST',
    success: function()
    {
        alert("Success");
    }
})
```

Готово!